# How to enable next tab previously disabled when form inside the first tab is submitted in jquery ui

Tags: jquery, jsp, jquery-ui

here is my code
the submit button

```
 <button type="submit" id="savepersonalinfo"  class="btn btn-primary pull-right ">Save info</button>
```

now i want the second tab to be visible
code:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({disabled: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]});
         //when the form inside tab-1 is submitted
         $("#savepersonalinfo").click(function() {

        $("#tabs").tabs({enabled:[1,2]} );
        });
```

[snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6awv6.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe with [option active](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active). From example:

```js
$("#tabs").tabs({enabled:[1,2]});
$("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", 2);
```